# How to refactor fast in intellij - move instance method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

What is the **fastest** way in Intellij to refactor a java instance method to another class in terms of (refactoring) steps.

For example:

```
public class Bar {
    public String getX(){
        return "x";
    }
}

public class Foo {
}

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bar().getX();
    }
}
```

Refactor to:

```
public class Bar {
}

public class Foo{
    public String getX(){
        return "x";
    }
}
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo().getX();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure about intellij, but I can imagine that is not a refactoring which can be done automatically, or at least in a general-enough way to make it useful: what instance of `Foo` should the `getX` method be invoked on?

Comment: The instance of `Foo` doesn't matter. `new Foo()` is fine or if all the instances of `Foo` in the program are `foo` the `foo` would be fine too.

Comment: Why not just refactor the name of class Bar to Foo (assuming Foo doesn't not exist)

Comment: Right - it might not matter *to you*, *in this case*, but in the general case it would. I can't see a broad-enough use case to warrant making that a built-in refactoring. I'd just get a cup of coffee and start hacking on sed... :(

Comment: If the method really is as trivial as it is here (and I'm guessing it's not), you can make `Bar.getX()` call the static method `Foo.getX()`, then inline all of the calls to `Bar.getX()`.

Comment: @BOND Ha, good one, but hey, let's assume that Foo and Bar do exist and the method should move :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply the "move method" refactoring with IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262803/how-can-i-apply-the-move-method-refactoring-with-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntellJ IDEA 15 you can do:

1. Position on the method `getX();`
2. Press Ctrl/Cmd+F6 (Change Signature)
3. Add parameter: Type=`Foo`, name=`foo`, Default value=`new Foo()`
4. Press F6: Move method
5. Select `Foo foo` as destination and press Refactor

Answer (score 1):

You can rename class/method/variable with Shift+F6 (just select name and press hotkeys), but You should aware that it don't remove or change already existed name, so you will get a duplicate. The best option remove Foo class before you rename Bar class.